# Xvfb IO Error: client killed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, headless, xvfb

I'm running the following pyqt application on an xvfb server on amazon ec2 ubuntu 12.04, I get the correct ouput from the qt application but I always get the aforementioned error when the app is done. Why am I getting this error? I think it may be because the xvfb server is not terminating correctly but I'm not sure.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb


args = {"nolisten":"tcp"}
vdisplay = Xvfb(**args)
vdisplay.start()
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
def update():
    print "upd"
t = QTimer()
t.start(500)
t.timeout.connect(update)
stopTimer = QTimer(timeout=app.quit,singleShot=True)
stopTimer.start(4000)
app.exec_()
print "done with app"
vdisplay.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

For me @urim's solution does not work because if you don't use `vdisplay.stop()`, the Xvfb process is **not** killed when the script exits, which is a problem. My solution is to explicitly kill the process with a background call, after a short while:

```
# Workaround for a problem preventing vdisplay.stop() to work
# normally, because apparently Qt is still keeping its handle on X
# at this point.
import os
os.system('(sleep 5 && kill -9 %d) &' % vdisplay.proc.pid)
```

Comment: Sleeping for a short time after termination also resolves similar error messages when running directly using xvfb-run (although I copied and modified xvfb-run to do so)

Answer (score 1):

Another ugly way to work around this is to wrap everything in another subprocess:

```
import xvfbwrapper
import sys
import subprocess as sub

with xvfbwrapper.Xvfb():
    p = sub.Popen(
        ["python", "yourscript.py"] + sys.argv[1:],
        stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE
    )
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print stdout
    print >> sys.stderr, stderr
    sys.exit(p.returncode)
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error as long as the `QApplication` instance is alive.  One solution is to push the `Xvfb.stop()` call closer to the exit of the program, for instance with the `atexit` module:

```
import atexit

# ...

def main():
    vdisplay = Xvfb()
    vdisplay.start()
    atexit.register(vdisplay.stop)

    # ...
```